# Assigning two tweens to kineticjs object but conditionally executing only one

Tags: javascript, kineticjs, tween

I have the following scenario. A blue rectangle and two tweens assigned to it from which only one will be executed depending on a conditional. Unfortunately the code below is not working:

```
var rectangle = new Kinetic.Rect ({
    width: 128, height: 64,
    fillRed: 0, fillGreen: 0, fillBlue: 255
});

var rectTweenFail = new Kinetic.Tween ({
    node: rectangle,
    duration: 5,
    easing: Kinetic.Easings.Linear,
    fillRed: 255, fillGreen: 0, fillBlue: 0,
});

var rectTweenPass = new Kinetic.Tween ({
    node: rectangle,
    duration: 5,
    easing: Kinetic.Easings.Linear,
    fillRed: 0, fillGreen: 255, fillBlue: 0,
});

if (some conditional)
    rectTweenPass.play();
else
    rectTweenFail.play();
```

Only if the conditional is true then the tween is executed. **Added** fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/yXRct/

**Note** that if I reverse the order of the `rectTweenFail` and `rectTweenPass` definitions then only if the conditional is false then the tween is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Update

Based on the fiddle @gaitat provided [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yXRct/), this looks like a bug to me. It does not behave as I would have expected. Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/klenwell/yXRct/8/) that distills the issue.

@gaitat has opened a bug report: https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/issues/973

---

#### Original Answer

Here are a couple fiddles based on your code. The first is a simple implementation of the true / false condition in your question:

http://jsfiddle.net/klenwell/R49Pg/

You can change the `PASS` var setting to verify both true and false cases work as expected.

The second example is more interesting:

http://jsfiddle.net/klenwell/5HB5h/

The conditional logic is event-based:

```
layer.find('.rectangle').on('dragstart dragend', function(evt) {
    if ( evt.type == 'dragstart' ) {
        console.log('pass');
        rectTweenPass.play();
    }
    else {
        console.log('fail');
        rectTweenFail.play();
    }
});
```

I notice one unexpected behavior that might be related to your issue:

With the event-based logic, it is easy for the tweens to step on one another. To see what I mean, drag the rectangle for only a second or so then release it and you'll see the fail tween interrupt the pass one. Watching the console log helps track the events.

Also note that if your tweens can be run multiple times, you'll need to reset the tweens between each call. You can see in my example that, after the first execution, when each tween is called, it appears to just skip to the finish without the animation. This, too, could contribute to unexpected behavior.

Comment: Your first fiddle is exactly the code I have. In my case though it is not working. Will investigate.

Comment: This fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yXRct/ closer resemples the situation I am facing. You notice that if you replace tha finish() with play() then it does not work even for square1. for square2 nothing happens.

Comment: @gaitat Try adding the node to your layer before you create the tweens. I had come across the issue with my examples. See http://jsfiddle.net/klenwell/yXRct/3/. What is odd here is that, although everything now seems to work for the false case, for the true case, the fail tween for `square2` still doesn't fire.

Comment: Thank you. You are right about the location I add the rectangle to the layer. The problem with `square2` is the one I cant figure out.

Comment: @gaitat Here's the problem slightly refactored: http://jsfiddle.net/klenwell/yXRct/7/. So the problem seems to be with the creation of the tweens. When `addTweens` is called for `square1`, both tweens gets associated with it. But when it is then called for `square2`, only the fail tween will function. Specifically, whichever tween is added first by that function, *when called for `square2`*, will not work. My impulse is to attribute it to some kind of obscure asynchronous loading issue but the truth is I have no explanation at moment.

Comment: @gaitat Maybe this warrants a bug report. Here's a further refinement of the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/klenwell/yXRct/8/. Toggle the `disableTween2` var to reproduce the issue. The underlying problem, it seems, is that the `Kinetic.Tween` constructor is not idempotent.

Comment: Do you think I should use two layers, one for pass and one for fail and use visibility, to currently solve my issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57443/discussion-between-klenwell-and-gaitat).